# Why does this code compile fine in java 11?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static <T> T defaultIfNull(T object, T defaultValue) {
        return object != null ? object : defaultValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> ls = Collections.emptyList();
        List<String> lo = defaultIfNull(ls, Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

With `openjdk 11`, it compiles fine:

```
root@debian:~/tmp# java -version
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Debian-1deb10u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Debian-1deb10u1, mixed mode, sharing)

root@debian:~/tmp# javac ./Main.java
```

But, that's not the case with `openjdk 1.8`:

```
root@debian:~/tmp# /usr/local/java-se-8u41-ri/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_41"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_41-b04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
root@debian:~/tmp# /usr/local/java-se-8u41-ri/bin/javac ./Main.java
./Main.java:12: error: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
        List<String> lo = defaultIfNull(ls, Collections.emptyList());
                                       ^
    inferred: List<? extends Object>
    upper bound(s): List<String>,Object
1 error
```

The problem here is that, `Collections.emptyList` returns `List<Object>` if no type parameter is supplied. Then, what makes it okay to `openjdk 11` to do the same thing?

Comment: I've tried to run the code on some online compiler, it compiles just fine on both versions 11.0.4 and 1.8.0_66.

Comment: @Amongalen In fact, `IntelliJ` also compiles it fine with `1.8` enabled (on my separate device). I'm not sure what's causing this problem.

Comment: Maybe you should try to compile it on that separate device with exactly the same version of openjdk. I can just guess that it is some bug that causes the problem.

Comment: @Amongalen Hmm, can you explain why it should work? I'm not sure how `emptyList` returns `List<String>` in this case. That would certainly prove why the latter is a bug.

Comment: Java 8 Update 41 is extremely old, the latest one is Java 8 Update 252.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [bug in the javac tool](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8055963) (as listed [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/8u60-bugfixes-2620228.html)) that has been fixed in a later version. You should update your jdk to a newer version to fix this problem (and to also apply the security patches).

Also, if can't update your jdk version you might be able to help the compiler by specifying the type, like so:

```java
List<String> lo = Main.<List<String>>defaultIfNull(ls, Collections.<String>emptyList());
```

I haven't tested this though, because I don't use your version, but it might work in this case.

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate on why it should work? I'm not sure, without specifying `<String>`, how `emptyList` returns `List<String>`.

Comment: @b1sub This is how [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-18.html) works. You can also specify the type but in general it's simply not necessary. The compiler is able to figure the type out by itself.

Comment: Okay. I'll dig it further. Thanks for the answer.